# Devise omniauth database constraints error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

Hi in my rails application I am using devise and omniauth. In that I had some strange problem whenever I use twitter,facebook and linkedin authentication together any one is working correctly another one is giving this error

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO      "users" ("created_at", "provider", "uid", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

In user mdoel

```
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
            user.provider =auth.provider
            user.uid=auth.uid
        end
     end
```

if like this measn linkedin working and

```
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
            user.provider =auth.provider
            user.uid=auth.uid
            user.email=auth.info.email
        end
     end
```

if like this means twitter is working otherwise all gives same error what will I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Devise generates the migration for the users table, it includes a unique index on the email address. Devise also sets up the schema so that email defaults to "", rather than null.

So when you are trying to save an email-less record, it is finding an existing one with the email address of "". Since email addresses must be unique, an error is being thrown.

You could try to change the schema so that the uniqueness works a little differently. For example:

```
class ChangeEmailUniqueness < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_index "users", :name =>"index_users_on_email" 
    add_index "users", ["email", "provider", "uid"], :name => "index_users_on_identity", :unique => true
  end

  def down
    remove_index "users", :name => "index_users_on_identity"
    add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  end
end
```

This isn't perfect because it would allow you to have the same email registered with two different providers.

You could also try a migration like this:

```
class ChangeUserEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users, :email, :string, null: true
  end
end
```

This would allow email address to be saved as null and won't trigger the uniqueness error message.